# objective c class type checking

Tags: objective-c, class

I use MagicalRecord (which is a category for NSManagedObject) to fetch my models. Then I display them using a generic table view controller which display my data based on the Class name.

The problem is that when I want to fetch these data I use something like this:

```
Class type = NSClassFromString(modelName);
NSArray *model = [type MR_findAll];
```

This compile and run perfectly, excepts that xcode displays a nasty error: "No know class method for MR_findALL".

Can I do something like a "Class cast" to NSManagedObject so the error will disappear? I want to keep it dynamic, I don't want to define a condition for all my models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define a protocol that includes `MR_findAll`.  Cast your object to that protocol before making the call.

`[(id<FindAllProtocol>)type MR_findAll]`

Comment: This is not the problem. You will find that declaring your protocol, but removing the `(id<FindAllProtocol>)`, will still solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not static type checking. `Class`, like `id`, disables static type checking.

The problem is something else: in Objective-C, in order to send a message using the `[... ...]` syntax, the compiler must have first seen the declaration of such a method *somewhere*. The reason that the compiler needs a declaration is that the compiler must compile a message dispatch to either a `objc_msgSend` or a `objc_msgSend_stret` call behind the scenes. Which one depends on the return type of the method. Therefore, it must know the types of the method (from a declaration) in order to compile a call to it.

Note, I said "somewhere", because that "somewhere" can be completely unrelated to where you use it. You could declare a dummy protocol that contains a declaration of the same message, *that is never used anywhere*, and it will serve the purpose of having a declaration. Or you can declare a category that contains it. Whatever. This might seem rather incredible to you. But if you take @HotLicks's solution with the protocol, and remove the cast, it will still not have the warning, because whether the protocol is used does not matter -- it's the declaration that is relevant here.

Comment: You are right the cast is useless. It's really hard to grasp objc dynamic nature sometimes. Thanks a lot, that's a very interesting aspect of the language.

Answer (score -2):

Try to cast your type variable to id, which is a dynamic typing.

Comment: @iSofTom this is not the problem.

Comment: This is not the problem. `Class` already disables static type checking, just like `id`